# Error connect Mysql with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl all html_code in url and take them in db MySQL.

But I have error. 
**Error 1054: Unknown column '$**

I have tried many ways but can not fix the error.
It made me take a lot of time. I just learn scrapy.
Hope everyone can help me fix this. Thank you

Spider_find.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from find.items import WebsiteLoader, FindItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
class FindSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "find"
    allowed_domains = ["tratu.soha.vn"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://tratu.soha.vn/dict/vn_vn/Sang",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = FindItem()
        sel = response.xpath('//*')
        item['html_code'] = sel.xpath('//*').extract()[0]
        #print item['html_code']
        print "CODE HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEe"
        yield item
```

pipelines.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import hashlib
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import sys
import MySQLdb

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'root'
    password = 'success'
    db = 'find2'
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            #self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO find2.website(html_code) VALUES ({0})""".format((item['html_code'].encode('utf8')))) 
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO  `find2`.`website`(`html_code`) VALUES (`${0}`)""".format((item['html_code'].encode('utf8'))))
            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRO"
            print "Error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1])
        return item
```

Comment: It would make this question much more useful when you reduce the wall of code (which is totally unconnected to the issue) to a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: I'll pay attention next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your error occurs during

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO  `find2`.`website`(`html_code`) 
    VALUES (`${0}`)""".format((item['html_code'].encode('utf8'))))
```

(would have been very helpful to include that information in the question right away ;).

This is because `str.format()` does not use `$`-syntax but `%`-syntax. In this simple case I would try

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO  `find2`.`website`(`html_code`) 
    VALUES (`%s`)""" % item['html_code'].encode('utf8'))
```

But generally you should *never* code like this but always use placeholder syntax and apply the value as parameters. In this very case, you actuallly **have to**, because you do not have a clue how the HTML code looks like. And HTML is very likely to contain a `'`. This will destroy the syntax of the SQL you build by string composition: The first `'` in the HTML will effectively close the value in the SQL giving raise to an ill-formed SQL.

So go for placeholder syntax:

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO  `find2`.`website`(`html_code`) 
    VALUES (%s)""", (item['html_code'].encode('utf8'),))
```

Let's see whether the next issue is the dot in the table name...

Comment: table website : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `find2`.`website` (
  `html_code` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

Comment: What is the error with the suggested code change (it cannot complain about `$` any longer...?)

Comment: not or no $ this is error " Error 1054: Unknown column '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="vi" lang="vi" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 
<!-- 
Js ming id

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' in 'field list'
"

Comment: exactly what should I do?

Comment: But I have next error. My urls have language VietNam. html code when I get it, these characters are not formatted !! What should I do ?

Comment: Charset is `utf-8` in the HTML. What do you mean by "not formatted"?

Comment: I mean some characters not formatted . ex when I crawl "<h5> <span class="mw-headline"> di chuyá»ƒn Ä‘áº¿n má»™t nÆ¡i khÃ¡c vá»›i nÆ¡i mÃ¬nh Ä‘ang á»Ÿ vÃ  thÆ°á»ng lÃ  á»Ÿ bÃªn cáº¡nh (cÃ³ ranh giá»›i trá»±c tiáº¿p vÃ  rÃµ rÃ ng) </span></h5>"

Comment: Your database content is ok. What you see on screen very much depends on how you display it. Please have a read here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html This is really too much for a comment to explain.

Comment: Thank. You help me very much !! Have nice day.

Comment: I will :) One last hint: Personally I am locked in `python2.6` because of compatibility issues. If I had the free choice, and do this web scraping thing, I whould seriously consider `python3` because of the *much* more intuitive unicode support. Compare https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html and you will know what I mean. But I am very opinionated. Others have other opinions: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/5/unicode-in-2-and-3/

Comment: @flashbier : Please vote my question. I need 50 repulation.

Answer (score 1):

To format a string in python i would usually do : `'{0} {1}'.format('one', 'two')`.

So, try removing the `$` sign from your query :

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO  `find2`.`website`(`html_code`) VALUES (`{0}`)""".format((item['html_code'].encode('utf8'))))
```

Comment: I try remove the "$" sign. But it's still error. Error not change.